# How to position topLevel() widget relative to root window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a topLevel widget and was wondering if there was a way to position the new window relative to the root window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get `root` window position:

```
x = root.winfo_x()
y = root.winfo_y()
```

Use `geometry` to set the position:

```
w = toplevel.winfo_width()
h = toplevel.winfo_height()  
toplevel.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x + dx, y + dy))
```

where `dx` and `dy` are the offsets from the current position.

Comment: An advice: if you know the target position, you should change it to: toplevel.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, target_x, target_y))). It's useful when you are dragging an widget and the target coordinate will be provided in `event` argument as `event.x_root`, `event.y_root`.

Answer (score 8):

You can skip getting/setting the dialog width/height and set only its X, Y position:

```
x = root.winfo_x()
y = root.winfo_y()
toplevel.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x + 100, y + 200)))
```

Replace 100 and 200 with relative X, Y to your root window.