# Tkinter Positioning widget

Tags: python, tkinter, module

I have a question. I import a module into the main window A which opens in a separate window B. Both windows have dimensions I have imposed. How do I position window B relative to A? Currently, window B appears in the upper right corner when called and I want to have it in the middle of window A. Thank you for your help :D

```
def get_gallery(self):
    from GUI.module.gallery import Gallery
    Gallery(tk.Toplevel(self.root)).pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def get_run_gallery(self):
    jpg = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Gallery", command=self.get_gallery)
    self.my_canvas.create_window(780, 220, anchor="nw", window=jpg, height=50, width=200)
```

### After changes

```
def get_gallery(self):
    from GUI.module.gallery import Gallery
    Gallery(tk.Toplevel(self.root)).pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    x = self.root.winfo_x()
    y = self.root.winfo_y()
    tk.Toplevel(self.root).geometry("+%d+%d" % (x + 600, y + 800))
```

I further have another question, with this code I have two Gallery windows open and an offset blank window, and I want to offset Gallery, how to correct this code? Thx for your help :D

Comment: Does your code snippet has something to do with your question? Because what you have wrote, I would interpret much different from what I expect from your code.

Comment: Yes, into the code I import a module that results in a photo gallery and I want to set it in the main window.

Comment: Have you looked at [this questions accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36050192/13629335)?

Comment: hadn't seen it, thanks for the link, I'll take a look

Comment: sometimes we dont know the terms we are looking for. You are welcome.

Comment: That's just the way it is, when I put a question in google there are buttons etc... and such imoprt is not typical (I think) and I have trouble finding the answer.

Comment: I face the same issue more often than I would like. Searching for a specific answer to a general problem. What I try to do is to boiler it down into smaller steps and search for it and than tweak it together. In your case I searched `tkinter position toplevel relative to root` and it poped up. I mark your question as duplicate, since someone else could search for your wording.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position topLevel() widget relative to root window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050192/how-to-position-toplevel-widget-relative-to-root-window)

Comment: I further have another question, with this code I have two Gallery windows open and an offset blank window, and I want to offset Gallery, how to correct this code? Thx for your help :D

Comment: position it relative to your offset window instead of main